# Understanding the Differences Between 'In' and 'Into' in English Usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

I am currently learning English and have come across a point of confusion regarding the use of the prepositions 'in' and 'into.' While they seem similar, I understand that their usage can significantly change the meaning of a sentence.

Could someone please explain the key differences between 'in' and 'into'? Are there specific rules or contexts that dictate when to use one over the other? I am particularly interested in examples that illustrate their distinct uses, as this would greatly aid my understanding.

Comment: Or [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/346513/the-usage-of-in-into-on-onto/346567#346567)?